# How to prevent snakemake from stopping after failed test suite?

Tags: python, pytest, snakemake

I am attempting to automate integration testing with snakemake (I need the output from some of the files so this seemed like a good tool). However when I need to run two test suites in pytest, the workflow stops if a single test in either suite fails. So for example I have:

```
rule run_tests:
    run:
        commands = [
            "pytest test_that_should_fail",
            "pytest test_that_should_succeed"
        ]
        for c in commands:
            shell(c)
```

And I need the output of the test that should fail for the latter test. Is there a way to prevent snakemake from stopping after running "pytest test_that_should_fail" ? Additionally snakemake stops without any sort of error message just a generic: "Error in rule run_tests: jobid: 0"

Comment: Does using `--verbose` on snakemake command help to show the output of the  commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write something like:

```
commands = [
   "pytest test_that_should_fail || true",
   "pytest test_that_should_succeed || true",
]
```

Then the shell commands will have exit code 0, which means succes, thus proceeding to execute other commands.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you let Snakemake deal with the different tests by running only one test per rule instance.

This could be done as follows (not tested):

```python
TESTS = ["test_that_should_fail", "test_that_should_succeed"]

rule all:
    input:
        logs = expand("{test}.log", test=TESTS),
        errs = expand("{test}.err", test=TESTS),

rule run_test:
    output:
        log = "{test}.log",
        err = "{test}.err",
    shell:
        """
        pytest {wildcards.test} 1> {output.log} 2> {output.err}
        """
```

Then, you can use option `-k` of snakemake to be sure all tests will be run.
But it would probably be cleaner to use `|| true` (as suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67393425/1878788)) if a non-zero return code is something expected.